# .NET xslt Extension Object not found

Tags: .net-3.5, xls, extension-objects

I am trying to implement a .NET xslt extension object the checks for the existence of an xml file following examples from [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1348981.aspx/1) and [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject(v=vs.90).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2). I also pondered some related SO posts which weren't much help.

When I try to find the extension with the following code snippet, it displays "Extension function is not available":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:XsltExtensionObject="urn:XsltExtensionObject"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl XsltExtensionObject">
```

...

```
<xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="function-available('XsltExtensionObject:getFile')">
          Extension function is available
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
          Extension function  is not available
     </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

...

I created a separate class library called XsltExtensionObject within the same VS 2012 solution as follows (did t in VB to be consistent with the first example):

```
Public Class FileExist
    Private exist As Boolean
    Public Sub New()
        exist = False
    End Sub
    Public Function getFile(ByVal myFile As String) As Boolean
        exist = System.IO.File.Exists(myFile)
        Return exist
    End Function
End Class
```

I execute the xsl transform as follows:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(MapPath("homepage.xslt"));
        XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
        XsltExtensionObject.FileExist obj = new XsltExtensionObject.FileExist();
        xslArgs.AddExtensionObject("urn:XsltExtensionObject", obj);
        xmldoc.Load(MapPath("lists.xml"));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        xslt.Transform(new XmlNodeReader(xmldoc), null, sw);
        content.InnerHtml = sw.ToString();
    }
```

Why can't it find the extension? What am I missing here? An assembly reference?

Answer (score 0):

There are two points I would like to present to others baffled by Xslt Object Extensions. Firstly, when I opened the xml document using XPathDocument not XmlDocument as shown in the [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts9by56w.aspx) the extension function was found.

Secondly, the class containing the extension (FileExist above) does NOT need to be created as a class library. Here's the C# code that worked:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(MapPath("lists.xml"));
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load(MapPath("homepage.xslt"));
        XsltArgumentList xslArgs = new XsltArgumentList();
        FileExist obj = new FileExist();
        xslArgs.AddExtensionObject("urn:XsltExtensionObject", obj);
        XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
        settings.CloseOutput = false;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw, settings))
            {
                xslt.Transform(xmldoc, xslArgs, xw, null);
            }
            content.InnerHtml = sw.ToString();
        }            
    }
    public class FileExist
    {
        bool exist = false;
        public bool getFile(string myFile)
        {
            exist = File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(myFile));
            return exist;
        }
    }
```